# I want to delete same innerText in two array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, foreach

When I clicked delete-button (.btn-wrap>li>button) , I hope to remove className("added") of same innerText with JavaScript.

```
<div class="table">
  <ul>
    <li class="added">list_1</li>
    <li class="added">list_2</li>
    <li class="added">list_3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<ul class="btn-wrap">
  <li>
    <span>list_1</span>
    <button class="delete"></button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>list_2</span>
    <button class="delete"></button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>list_3</span>
    <button class="delete"></button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please provide your js code

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to remove the element's text content for a particular class? or you wish to remove the class basing on the elemen't text content?

Comment: @Link The second one~ I wish to remove the class basing on the element text content !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The question was not clear. However, after going through the attached HTML and the question itself one more time, I revised my answer.

My understanding of the question: The OP is looking to remove a class from the above list elements basing on the 'delete' button click from the below list. I have now modified my code snippet to achieve this. Please let me know if this is not what you are looking for, so I can make modifications to my solutions accordingly.

```js
const addedList = document.querySelectorAll('.added');

document.querySelectorAll('.delete').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const deletedVal = e.target.previousSibling.previousSibling.textContent;
    addedList.forEach(listItem => {
      if (listItem.textContent === deletedVal) {
        listItem.classList.remove('added');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.added {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
          <ul>
            <li class="added">list_1</li>
            <li class="added">list_2</li>
            <li class="added">list_3</li>
          </ul>
        <ul class="btn-wrap">
          <li>
            <span>list_1</span>
            <button class="delete">Delete</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>list_2</span>
            <button class="delete">Delete</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>list_3</span>
            <button class="delete">Delete</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: @HBDIDI can you please confirm if my solution provides you the solution you are looking for? If not, please let me know what you are exactly looking for.

Comment: @Teemu I have modified my solution, so now the class gets removed as per the delete button that is clicked.